# How to use a transfer function from an EOA holding a token to a contract address?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I am using an ERC20 token which is used by a smart contact, EOAs also holds tokens

How can I use the transfer function for transferring tokens from the EOA to a different Smart Contract address .

when I use the function transfer within the contract which is to be funded from an account which calls the parent function,

can it be done like this ?
`tokenContractInstance.transfer(address(this), _bidValue);`

will the tokens be debited from the msg.sender of the parent function ?

Thank You

Comment: If the contract calls `transfer`, then the tokens will be transferred from the contract. I think you're looking for `approve` (called by the token owner) and then `transferFrom` (called by the contract).

Comment: Yeah got it , I was thinking that , if the msg.sender of the parent function gets delighted call to the transfer func . Got it now , Thanks a lot

Comment: How to call approve on behalf token owner when you are inside the contract to which you are sending the contract.   Suppose EOA wants to approve the contract, Inside a function can the EOA call  `tokenInstance.approve(address(this), _tokenAmount)` , will this function be called on behalf of msg.sender(EOA) or the smart contract calling the function?

Comment: If that code is in the contract, then it's the contract doing the approving. You need the EOA to call `approve` on the token contract.

Comment: can you guide me how to do that with an example? It will be very helpful

Comment: You just do it the same way you call any function. E.g. in web3.js 1.0: `tokenContract.methods.approve(contractAddress, amount);`